# IKFast solver always returns zero for a joint value

Tags: ros, ikfast

I'm working on inverse kinematics for a ur16e robot manipulator (6DOF) attached to a mobile base. Following [a tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ikfast/ikfast_tutorial.html), I generate an IKFast solver from the URDF file of the whole robot (the baselink and eelink are chosen to match ones of the robot arm). The resulting .cpp solver is then made an executable for the use.

However, when given an input as a set of values representing the position and orientation of the end effector, the resulting output is not correct. From the 6 joint angles for the 6 axes, the value for the 5th angle is always zero, no matter which orientation is given as an input.

For example, an input would look something like this:

```
r00 r01 r02 t0 r10 r11 r12 t1 r20 r21 r22 t2

0 1 0 0.5 0 0 1 0.5 1 0 0 0.5
```

And a solution would look something like this:

```
[0.902574921849587, -2.626397212736598, -0.61608885723397, 0.100893416380779, 0.0, -1.570796326794897]
```

From trial and error, giving these values to the actual (virtual) robot, it seems that the other joint angle values (or at least from the 1st to the 4th one) might actually be correct. That's because, with the other joint values in place, I can just manually rotate the 5th joint and reach the expected end effector poses.

Do any of you have any idea what could cause such an error?

Comment: You can find the .cpp code in the attachment here --> [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/3493)